# why an object created in the code behind is not available in the aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple question. When we create an object in the code behind(".aspx.cs"), why is it not available in the aspx page.

For example, if I have a class(present in another .cs file and not in the code behind) and in that class I have a property declared, lets say "Name".

```
namespace BLL.SO
{
    public class SOPriceList
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name;}
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I create an object, lets say "obj" in the code behind(".aspx.cs"), with scope within the partial class.

```
namespace Modules.SO
{    
    public partial class PriceListRecordView : PageBase
    {
        SOPriceList obj = new SOPriceList();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Using this object "obj" I can access the property. Then why can't I use the same object "obj" to get the property in the aspx page in this manner,

```
<%= obj.Name%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when I create an object, lets say "obj" in the code
>   behind(".aspx.cs"), using this object "obj" I can access the property

It's not clear how exactly you created this `obj` instance. If it is some local variable inside a method in the code behind it is obvious that the scope of this variable is the method itself so you cannot access it in the ASPX page.

In the ASPX page you can only access members of the current WebForm which are defined in the code behind. So this `obj` must be instantiated somewhere. You could for example have a property in your code behind:

```
protected SomeType MyObj
{
    get 
    {
        return ... some instance
    }
}
```

and then in the ASPX page you could access it:

```
<%= MyObj.Name %>
```

Let's take another example which allows you to initialize the property for example in the `Page_Load` event:

```
protected SomeType MyObj { get; private set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyObj = new SomeType();
}
```

Comment: The object "obj" has scope within the partial class, in the code behind and not inside any function.

Comment: Could you show how exactly is this `obj` defined in your code behind if it is not inside a function? You have a property or something? What's its visibility?

Comment: @Bibhu: The key here is `protected`, you cannot access `private` members in a derived class.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Updated my question.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear now. Your `obj` variable is private so you cannot access it in the ASPX page. Make it protected: `protected SOPriceList obj = new SOPriceList();`. You probably might ask: but why is `obj` private? And the answer is because when you do not specify a visibility modifier when declaring a field in a class the C# compiler assumes `private`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Thanks, it works :) . I more question I tried, by making it public instead (out of curiosity) but it didn't work, can u please explain it to me.

Comment: `public` should work. It has even greater visibility level than `protected`. When you say `it didn't work` could you be a little more specific please? What didn't work? Did you get an error message? If yes, what error message did you get?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - oh yes. Its working, did a silly mistake. Many many Thanks to you, learnt a lot from you. :)